# UITableView Custom Cells Overlapping

Tags: ios, uitableview

Starting my quest into ios development but I have a problem, below.

The plan:
[image: the plan]

The result:
[image: the result]

Comment: Post the code for your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Are you responding to -heightForRowAtIndexPath: ?PS: Please post code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tableview needs to know the height of your custom cell, use the following tableview delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

        return 100.0;
    }

    return 200.0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Now I Have a problem that when I scroll down the view it springs back to the top when i release. So I cant get to the bottom button

Answer (score 5):

You need to set height of your custom cell using tableview delegate method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        return 150.0;
    }else if (indexPath.row == 1){
        return 300.0;
    }
    return 0.0;
}
```

as well as u need to set your custom cell cliptobound property to yes in datasource method

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      customcell *cell = (customcell *)[tableView dequeResusableCellWithIdentifier:@"newcell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
      cell.cliptobound = YES;
      return cell;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cells are getting reused without the content being reset in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  In that method you need to blank out the cell content before putting more content in it.